Stream API convert entity to JSON
I have a list of Entity which I got from repository.
[DataEntity(key=0a3e1588-ad59-3586-b071-d5001f5ff9a7, timestamp=2024-05-24 09:48:00.0, value=10.0),
DataEntity(key=0a3e1588-ad59-3586-b071-d5001f5ff9a7, timestamp=2024-05-24 09:46:00.0, value=11.0),
DataEntity(key=0a3e1588-ad59-3586-b071-d5001f5ff9a7, timestamp=2024-05-24 09:44:00.0, value=12.0),

DataEntity(key=b349f0ea-c810-3790-bdc3-a82ed5921a28, timestamp=2024-05-24 09:48:00.0, value=13.0),
DataEntity(key=b349f0ea-c810-3790-bdc3-a82ed5921a28, timestamp=2024-05-24 09:46:00.0, value=14.0),
DataEntity(key=b349f0ea-c810-3790-bdc3-a82ed5921a28, timestamp=2024-05-24 09:44:00.0, value=15.0),

DataEntity(key=63d29aeb-ab91-3d24-b40c-d69f2955a893, timestamp=2024-05-24 09:48:00.0, value=16.0),
DataEntity(key=63d29aeb-ab91-3d24-b40c-d69f2955a893, timestamp=2024-05-24 09:46:00.0, value=17.0),
DataEntity(key=63d29aeb-ab91-3d24-b40c-d69f2955a893, timestamp=2024-05-24 09:44:00.0, value=18.0)]

I don't know how to implement this is stream api way.
I want to convert this list into JSON using Stream API.
Does it make sense to use parallel stream or in my case, ordinary stream will be enough?
This is the expected structure:
{
    "0a3e1588-ad59-3586-b071-d5001f5ff9a7": [
        {
            "timestamp" : "2024-05-24 09:48:00.0",
            "value" : 10.0
        },
        {
            "timestamp" : "2024-05-24 09:46:00.0",
            "value" : 11.0
        }
        {
            "timestamp" : "2024-05-24 09:44:00.0",
            "value" : 12.0
        }
    ],

    "b349f0ea-c810-3790-bdc3-a82ed5921a28": [
        {
            "timestamp" : "2024-05-24 09:48:00.0",
            "value" : 13.0
        },
        {
            "timestamp" : "2024-05-24 09:46:00.0",
            "value" : 14.0
        }
        {
            "timestamp" : "2024-05-24 09:44:00.0",
            "value" : 15.0
        }
    ],

    "63d29aeb-ab91-3d24-b40c-d69f2955a893": [
        {
            "timestamp" : "2024-05-24 09:48:00.0",
            "value" : 16.0
        },
        {
            "timestamp" : "2024-05-24 09:46:00.0",
            "value" : 17.0
        }
        {
            "timestamp" : "2024-05-24 09:44:00.0",
            "value" : 18.0
        }
    ]

}

This is my implementation in ordinary style, but it looks ugly. How can I implement this using Stream API.
            List<DataEntity> dataEntityList = repository.getRecordCountForPeriod();

            Map response = new HashMap();
            for (DataEntity data : dataEntityList) {
                if(response.containsKey(data.getKey())){

                    List list = (List) response.get(data.getKey());
                    Map map = new HashMap<>();
                    map.put("timestamp", data.getTimestamp());
                    map.put("value", data.getInstancesValue());
                    list.add(map);

                }else{
                    List list = new ArrayList();
                    Map map = new HashMap<>();
                    map.put("timestamp", data.getTimestamp());
                    map.put("value", data.getInstancesValue());
                    list.add(map);
                    response.put(data.getKey(), list);
                }
            }


I want to convert this list into JSON using Stream API. - this is job for a json parser, gson, jackson, etc. Definitely not for the stream api.

@Chaosfire You don't understand my question . I updated my post

Are you using the old-fashioned java.sql.Timestamp class? And even for a purpose not related to SQL? Certainly don’t do that. For a timestamp use Instant or another appropriate class from java.time, the modern Java date and time API. The Timestamp class was a hack on top of the already poorly designed Date class. Both have been outdated for 10 years.

@Romillion Then edit your quesion accordingly, please. The title has no relation to the actual problem you want solved and is misleading. The same applies for the first half of the question.

Here is the working solution for your problem, created a DataRecord class that holds timestamp and value as field:
        List<DataEntity> list = List.of(
                new DataEntity("0a3e1588-ad59-3586-b071-d5001f5ff9a7", "2024-05-24 09:48:00.0", 10.0),
                new DataEntity("0a3e1588-ad59-3586-b071-d5001f5ff9a7", "2024-05-24 09:46:00.0", 11.0),
                new DataEntity("0a3e1588-ad59-3586-b071-d5001f5ff9a7", "2024-05-24 09:44:00.0", 12.0),
    
                new DataEntity("b349f0ea-c810-3790-bdc3-a82ed5921a28", "2024-05-24 09:48:00.0", 13.0),
                new DataEntity("b349f0ea-c810-3790-bdc3-a82ed5921a28", "2024-05-24 09:46:00.0", 14.0),
                new DataEntity("b349f0ea-c810-3790-bdc3-a82ed5921a28", "2024-05-24 09:44:00.0", 15.0),
    
                new DataEntity("63d29aeb-ab91-3d24-b40c-d69f2955a893", "2024-05-24 09:48:00.0", 16.0),
                new DataEntity("63d29aeb-ab91-3d24-b40c-d69f2955a893", "2024-05-24 09:46:00.0", 17.0),
                new DataEntity("63d29aeb-ab91-3d24-b40c-d69f2955a893", "2024-05-24 09:44:00.0", 18.0));
    
        Map<String, List<DataRecord>> map = Optional.ofNullable(list).orElse(Collections.emptyList()).stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(DataEntity::getKey,
                        Collectors.mapping(
                                dataEntity -> new DataRecord(dataEntity.getTimestamp(), dataEntity.getValue()),
                                Collectors.toList())));
    
        System.out.println(map);
        //output
//      {0a3e1588-ad59-3586-b071-d5001f5ff9a7=[DataRecord [timestamp=2024-05-24 09:48:00.0, value=10.0], 
//                                             DataRecord [timestamp=2024-05-24 09:46:00.0, value=11.0], 
//                                             DataRecord [timestamp=2024-05-24 09:44:00.0, value=12.0]], 
//      63d29aeb-ab91-3d24-b40c-d69f2955a893=[DataRecord [timestamp=2024-05-24 09:48:00.0, value=16.0], 
//                                            DataRecord [timestamp=2024-05-24 09:46:00.0, value=17.0], 
//                                            DataRecord [timestamp=2024-05-24 09:44:00.0, value=18.0]], 
//      b349f0ea-c810-3790-bdc3-a82ed5921a28=[DataRecord [timestamp=2024-05-24 09:48:00.0, value=13.0], 
//                                            DataRecord [timestamp=2024-05-24 09:46:00.0, value=14.0], 
//                                            DataRecord [timestamp=2024-05-24 09:44:00.0, value=15.0]]}
    
    public class DataRecord {
    
        private String timestamp;
        private double value;
    
        public DataRecord(String timestamp, double value) {
            super();
            this.timestamp = timestamp;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }


A stream which will return a Map<String, List> will do the trick. You just need to map the values as the response you are using. If you wanna use streams I suggest you flatmap function for each Entity and then collect them for use.
